# Trouble with time dependent variable reference

Tags: python, class, variables, time, variable-assignment

I to make a hidden button, that will show, when you hoer over it, then lights up upon pressing it for a short time (2 secs in my script atm) and then runs a function. I implemented a mechanism that appears logical to me to pull this off. Bit I get a variable reference error.

This is my button class:

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, imgInAc, imgAc, posX, posY, width, height, function, gameInstance, hiddenButton):
        self.imgInAc = pygame.image.load(imgInAc)
        self.imgAc = pygame.image.load(imgAc)
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
        self.w = width
        self.h = height
        self.function = function
        self.gameInstance = gameInstance
        self.hiddenButton = hiddenButton
        # Make clickDump false, to make sure, refTiem gets measured only once after the button press,
        # because otherweise it would get overwritten over and over again while the game loop is running
        self.clickDump = False 

    def button(self):
        # Measure the current time to later run the button function while displaying the active image before doing so.
        curTime = time.clock()
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if self.posX+self.w > mouse[0] > self.posX and self.posY+self.h > mouse[1] > self.posY:
            if self.hiddenButton == False:
                self.gameInstance.gameDisplay.blit(self.imgAc,(self.posX,self.posY))
                if click[0] == 1:
                    buttonFunctions.buttonFunctions(self.function)
            # If the button is a ahidden one, go through teh following protocol
            elif self.hiddenButton == True:
                # Display the off version if the mouse hovers over it
                self.gameInstance.gameDisplay.blit(self.imgInAc,(self.posX,self.posY))
                if click[0] == 1:
                    # if you click on it, display teh active version
                    self.gameInstance.gameDisplay.blit(self.imgAc,(self.posX,self.posY))
                    ###print curTime
                    # If clickDump is false, defien teh reference time relative to teh current time.
                    # Then make it true, so the ref time doesn't get changed again, while the game loop is running
                    if self.clickDump == False:
                        refTime = time.clock()+2
                        ###print refTime
                        self.clickDump = True
                # If ClickDump is true, check if teh time condition is satiesfied. Note, that this check is run outside the "if click[0] == 1"-scope,
                # to make sure, it also gets checked if the click happened in a previoues cycle.
                if self.clickDump == True:
                    # If the time interval between the click event and the current time has elapsed
                    # set clickDUmp back to flase, so it can be used for teh next button press protocol
                    # and finally run the button function.
                    if curTime > refTime:
                        self.clickDump = False
                        buttonFunctions.buttonFunctions(self.function)

        else:
            if self.hiddenButton == False:
                self.gameInstance.gameDisplay.blit(self.imgInAc,(self.posX,self.posY))
```

the error is:

"...line 296, in button

if curTime > refTime:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'refTime' referenced before assignment"

I really don't understand this, as I thought I only execute the part where the time variables are compared IF refTime has been initialized, because the condition or running the comparison onyl gets fulfilled in the part where refTime gets assigned its value.

Sorry for potential loads of typos in my commets... I only wrote them for myself.

So... me confused.

Comment: You only *set* `refTime` when `self.clickDump == False` (strictly, that should be `if not self.clickDump:`), and only *get* it when `self.clickDump == True` (again, that should be `if self.clickDump:`). They can't both be true.

Comment: But that is what I want to do. ...? isn't it. Where is the error in my logic there?

Comment: Typically, local variables cease to exist when the function ends. If you create `refTime` in the first call to `button`, it won't be there when you call `button` again.

Comment: You should use `if self.clickDump:` instead of `if self.clickDump == True:`. Same goes for `False`: `if not self.clickDump:`.

Comment: Ah! That has to be it. Thanks!

Comment: Not it works perfectly, after making refTime a class variable. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1):

it is due to the scope of `refTime`.

`reftime` is assigned in some `if` loop while used in another `if` loop.

assign it like this.

```
class Button(object):
    ...
    ...
    def button(self):
        refTime = 0
```

Comment: Then it will be a *class attribute*, shared by all `Button`s, which may lead to subtle and confusing errors later on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but in code it is not used any where else.

Comment: Even if the attribute is *only used* in `Button.button` (of which we've no guarantee), the fact that you could have several buttons sharing the same state is still a problem. Indeed, it's potentially *worse* than the current problem - silently doing the wrong thing is harder to fix than loudly failing.

Comment: I just realized something. Could I not just have manually updated the screen just before a sleep command before  buttonFunctions.buttonFunctions(self.function)?